# How to prove the existence of a real number $a$, dependent on the condititons of a particular sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I've been given the following problem from a Putnam exam, and the solution I've generated seems far less complicated than the one I've seen. The problem motivation states:

> Let $\{x_n\}$, $n\geq0$, be a sequence of nonzero real numbers such that ${x_n}^2-{x_{n-1}}{x_{n+1}}=1$ for $n=1,\ 2,\ 3,\ ...$.  Prove there exists a real number $a$ such that ${x_{n+1}}=ax_n-x_{n-1}$ for all $n\geq1$.

My solution is essentially that $$a=\frac{x_{n+1}+x_{n-1}}{x_n}$$ therefore $$x_{n-1},\ x_n,\ x_{n+1}\ \epsilon\ \mathbb{R}^{\lt0}\cup\mathbb{R}^{\gt0}\ \implies a\ \epsilon\ \mathbb{R}$$

Not to be flip, but proving that such a number exists seems trivial.  Is it implied that I should try to find an actual value for $a$? Have I actually proved that a real number must exist that fits the conditions of this sequence without having demonstrated a concrete value? I have this nagging feeling that I've left out something crucial, or that my solution is lacking in necessary rigor.

Comment: This is not a constant?

Comment: You are supposed to prove it's the same number $a$ for every $n$.  You haven't done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must prove that $a$ is a constant NOT dependent on $n$.

**Hint**

In fact $$a={x_0^2+x_1^2-1\over x_0x_1}$$Substitute and conclude (it was rather a long time to me to prove it :D).